# Ionic open page or tab from component and run function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm struggling with the following issue. In my Ionic (3) application. I got the oneSignal (push notifications) handling script in my app.component.ts file. I'm using the `handleNotificationOpened().subcribe` function to be able to open a page or run a function when a user presses the push notification.

Now my question is, how can I change tab or page from app.component.ts and run a page specific function while opening that tab/page.

For instance:

- User get notification that he has a new friendship invite.
- User presses the push notification
- App will open "friendlist" tab and opens the specific invite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people having the same question, I found the solution using events. It may not be the best solution but it works.

First you need to add the following components to your page.ts

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
```

The following function fires when the user press the pushnotification using OneSignal.

```
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data) => {
    // do something when a notification is opened

    // the following two lines pass data I send with the push notification so the app knows what to open
    let pushaction = data.notification.payload.additionalData.action;
    let pushactionvalue = data.notification.payload.additionalData.actionvalue;

    // this fires up the tab-switching
    this.runNotificationAction(pushaction, pushactionvalue);

});
```

The following function directs user to the right tab

```
runNotificationAction(pushaction, pushactionvalue){

    // this is the data passed the the other page
    let data = {"action": pushaction, "value:": pushactionvalue};

    // this opens the right tab. Make sure to change select '0' to the required tab (0 is the first one). 
    this.app.getRootNav().getActiveChildNav().select(0);

    // fires the function that passed the data. Using second parameter to filter event listeners per page. 
    this.sendData(data, 'homepage');    
}
```

And the function that submits the data to the other pages:

```
sendData(data, command){
    //We set a timeout because I had problems with sending it imediatly. Like this it works fine for me.
    setTimeout(() => {
        let pushcommand = "pushData:" + command ;
        this.events.publish(pushcommand, data);
    }, 500);
}
```

And at last we have to add an event listener on the other tabs/pages you are going to redirect to.

```
// making an event listerner command for each page like pushData:homepage makes sure the action is only fired from the specific page
this.events.subscribe('pushData:homepage', (data) => {
    console.log('Yes, data passed!');
    console.log(data);
   // Then you can fire your function and use the data
});
```

If anyone has any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: i am using but not redirecting to 3rd tab...it is redirecting to only first root or active tab. this.app.getRootNav().getActiveChildNav().select(3);